# Unable to drag and drop in Appium Android

Tags: android, appium, ui-automation

I'm using Appium 1.6.5 and Windows 10.

Using the demo app by Appium (ApiDemos-debug.apk), I am trying to drag and drop dots.

View app screen:

[image: screenshot]

This is my current code:

```
TouchAction actions = new TouchAction(driver);
actions.tap((AndroidElement)driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("text(\"Views\")")).perform();

driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("text(\"Drag and Drop\")").click();

AndroidElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("io.appium.android.apis:id/drag_dot_1"));

AndroidElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.id("io.appium.android.apis:id/drag_dot_2"));

actions.longPress(element1).waitAction(3000).perform().release();
```

This error prints when test is run:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be
>   located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Any combination of longPress() calls results in this error. I can click & tap, that's fine. When it comes to using other TouchAction methods, then errors occur.

Any idea how to resolve this? Need to know if it's my setup that's wrong or TouchAction method has issues.

Comment: If I were to add a new TouchAction variable (e.g. actions2) and use that to call another TouchAction method, it will work. Unsure if this an issue with the Appium version or the perform() method not clearing the command queue (if it's even meant to do that).

Answer (score 0):

You need to long press on that element and drag it to other element.Currently, you're only pressing long and performing the action without releasing it.

Try this:

```
actions.longPress(element1).moveTo(element2).release().perform();
```